# Spring oauth2 openid connect logout user upon token revocation

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, salesforce, openid, logout

I'm using the Spring OAuth2 from the 2.0.1 release.
I have successfully authenticated the user in the RP app upon successful completion of OpenID connect flow with the Salesforce as the provider.

Now after the successful authentication, the token is revoked sometime later at the Salesforce site through the API: https://na17.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/revoke?token=

But even after the token is revoked, the user can make authenticated REST API calls to the RP app, unaffected.  The question is, is there a mechanism in Spring OAuth2 framework to detect the revocation on the provider side so that I can logout the user in the RP app?

FYI, the openid connect spec describes how this can be done theoretically: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html